# How to inject singleton objects produced into factory

Tags: java, spring, oop

Even after going through similar questions on factory and dependency injection, I couldn't find an answer.

Let's say I have a `EventHandler` factory which gives out different kind of `EventHandler` based on event type. Each type of `EventHandler` has it's own dependencies used in handling that event and these could be different from other `EventHandler` type.

```
public interface EventHandler {
   void handle(Event e);
}

public class EventHandlerA implements EventHandler{
  private DependencyA depA;
  //constructors for depA
}

public class EventHandlerB implements EventHandler{
  private DependencyB depB;
  //constructors for depB
} 

public class Factory {
 public EventHandler getHandler(EventType type) {
    if(type.equals("A")) {
        //return instance of EventHandlerA
    }
 }
}

@Configuration
public class Configuration {
  @Bean
  public EventHandler eventHandlerA() { return new EventHandler(depA()); }

  @Bean
  public Factory factory() {  //.. ?? }
}
```

My question is - I am using `Spring` `@Configuration` with `@Bean` annotation to create singleton beans of all these event handlers and factory. How do I inject these beans of various event handlers into the factory so that factory can return these instances based on event type.

One direct approach I can think of is to just pass all the event handlers to factory during factory instantiation (via constructor) and maintain a mapping of type to handler and just do a get on that map. Downside of this approach is that whenever I need to add new event handler to the factory, I'll have to modify the constructor or add a new setter. Is there any better approach?

Comment: Is there any other detail I can provide if question is not very clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are alot of ways to go about doing this but here are 2 ways.

In your question you have this:

`public EventHandler eventHandlerA() { return new EventHandler(depA()); }`

Now I dont know if you intended to have this but your bean will be a different instance at every injection because it creates a new one every return statement. You've essentially made your configuration into a factory. I am going to assume that this is unintended.

## Method 1

---

I think this is the strategy I would use because you can add a boat load of handlers, you dont pollute your app context namespace and its clean and easy to follow. For this method I renamed `EventHandlerFactory` to `EventHandlerRepository` to make it more appropriate to its functionality.

When the configuration is loaded all the event handlers are added to the factory and then you can `@Autowire` that factory around your application then call `repository.getHandler(/*Type*/)`.

This same design pattern could be used to make a real factory by simply renaming `EventHandlerRepository` to `EventHandlerFactory` then passing it `Class<? extends EventHandler>` instead of actual instances and creating a new instance on `getHandler`.

**EventType:**

```
public enum EventType {
    A, B;
}
```

**EventHandlerRepository:**

```
public class EventHandlerRepository {
    private Map<EventType, EventHandler> handlers;

    public EventHandlerRepository() {
        handlers = new HashMap<EventType, EventHandler>();
    }

    void synchronized registerHandler(EventType type, EventHandler handler) {
        handlers.put(type, handler);
    }

    public synchronized EventHandler getHandler(EventType type) {
        return handlers.get(type);
    }
}
```

**Configuration:**

```
@Configuration
public class Configuration {

    private EventHandlerRepository repository = new EventHandlerRepository();

    public Config() {
        // register all your event handlers here
        factory.registerHandler(EventType.A, new EventHandlerA());
    }

    @Bean
    public EventHandlerRepository getEventHandlerRepository() {
        return repository;
    }
}
```

## Method 2

---

Simply add `@Component` to all your event handlers and make sure they are in your component scan path.

```
@Component
public class EventHandlerA implements EventHandler
```